# Jenkins server на CentOS7

Tags: virtualbox, jenkins

Всем привет!

Коллеги, нужна помощь!

Накатил на виртуалку (Virtualbox) CentOS и поднял на ней сервер Jenkins.
Хочу попасть теперь на него с основной машины, как slave http://JenkinsMasterHost:8080/
но попасть не удается. Сеть как только не настраивал, перепробовал разные адапторы виртуальной машины, все безрезультатно. Прописывал статический IP - Не катит.

Дополнительная информация:
Пинги с обоих сторон нормальные. Если сервер Jenkins ставлю на винде, то с виртуалки http://JenkinsMasterHost:8080/ захожу нормально, а вот наоборот - проблемы.

Может кто сталкивался с таким?

Comment: По IP заходит нормально? Если да, то стоит проверить `/etc/hosts`. Если нет - нужно проверить настройки SELinux и iptables.

Comment: Я с линухом и сетями только знакомлюсь, что значит "Заходит по IP?" через браузер http://server-ip-adress:8080/ - нет. Сеть я проверял только пингом из командной строки.

Comment: Как вы ставили jenkins на centos и вы его там запустили?

Answer (score 0):

Выключите firewall:

```
systemctl stop firewalld
```